# How to implement TreeTable in sapui5

Tags: sapui5

**i have a model like this**

```
[ {"name":"Main 1","description":"main1 Description",
         "children": [{
               "name": "SUB 1",
               "description": "SUB 1 Description",
               "children":[
                    {
                        "name": "SUB 1.1",
                        "description": "SUB 1.1 Description"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "SUB 1.2",
                        "description": "SUB 1.2 Description"
                    }         ]
                }],
                "parent":[{"name": "parent sub"}]
            },
   {"name":"Main 2","description":"main2 Description",children:[],parent:[]},
   {"name":"Main 3","description":"main3 Description",children:[],parent:[]},
   {"name":"Main 4","description":"main4 Description",children:[],parent:[]}
 ]
```

and i want to display `name` and `description` property. The contents in the `"children"` property should be a sub-level in the row, and i don't want to display `"parent"` content in this tree table. how can i restrict `"parent"` property from the tree table.

Answer (score 4):

The sap.ui.model.ClientTreeBinding used by the TreeTable with a JSONModel or XMLModel supports the parameter `arrayNames`.
This parameter expects an array of the model property names that will create a sublevel (if containing an object).

So in your example you should use something like this:

```
treeTable.bindRows({path: '/pathToData', parameters: { arrayNames: ['children'] }});
```

or in XMLView:

```
<TreeTable rows="{path: '/pathToData', parameters: { arrayNames: ['children'] } }" >
...
</TreeTable>
```

Theres not much to find in the documentation about this except for [one example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#test-resources/sap/ui/core/samples/databinding/DataBindingTreeLarge.html). You can find the source for the example [in the openui5 github](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/rel-1.32/src/sap.ui.core/test/sap/ui/core/samples/databinding/DataBindingTreeLarge.html#L118).

Answer (score 1):

**Try This Should Work**

```
var oData={
     "children":[ 
               {"name":"Main 1","description":"main1 Description", "children": [], "parent":[]},
               {"name":"Main 2","description":"main2 Description","children":[],parent:[]},
               {"name":"Main 3","description":"main3 Description","children":[],parent:[]},
               {"name":"Main 4","description":"main4 Description","children":[],parent:[]}
           ]
   };

var oTable = new sap.ui.table.TreeTable({
    columns: [
        new sap.ui.table.Column({label: "Name", template: "name"}),
        new sap.ui.table.Column({label: "Description", template: "description"})
    ],
    selectionMode: sap.ui.table.SelectionMode.Single,
    enableColumnReordering: true,
    expandFirstLevel: true,
    });

var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oModel.setData(oData);
oTable.setModel(oModel);
oTable.bindRows("/children");
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.But my problem occur when a sub-level exist.for eg if we have a list of children and parent under "Main 1" .Then it should display both children and parent under the main 1 row.I don't want to display "parent" property.Only children should come under sub level.

Comment: This Can not be achieved by SAP UI5 standard Tree Table. you can not bind the tree table this way. only can only bind with a particular path. Thank you