# OpenUI5 TreeTable bindRows with factory function

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am trying to bind data to a TreeTable using a factory function.

When using column templates everything is working as expected: http://jsbin.com/givaha/8/edit?html,output

But replacing the template with a factory function does not work (empty table):
http://jsbin.com/givaha/11/edit?html,output

I have been looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25200913/how-to-implement-treetable-in-sapui5/33289385#33289385) as well where some undocumented parameter for showing which attributes are arrays is mentioned, but using that does not seem to help either.

I have been looking through the source code of OpenUI5 and note that `bindRows` must be called since `bindAggregation` [does not set the proper parameters](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/rel-1.32/src/sap.ui.table/src/sap/ui/table/TreeTable.js#L128-L134).

The factory function does not seem to be called at all for some reason.

I get the impression that [templates translate to factory functions automatically](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/rel-1.32/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/base/ManagedObject.js#L2898-L2900) and those are called properly, then why not my factory function?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="description" content="TreeTable with Factory">
  <script src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
          id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
          data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
          data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons,sap.ui.table"
          data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax="complex"
          data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge">
  </script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="stuff"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var data = {
            'root': [
                {
                    'label': 'node1',
                    'children': [
                        {
                            'label': 'node1.1'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    'label': 'node2'
                },
                {
                    'label': 'node3'
                }
            ]
        };

        var model = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        model.setData(data);

        var table = new sap.ui.table.TreeTable({
            'columns': [
                new sap.ui.table.Column({
                    'label': 'Column 1'
                })
            ]
        });

        table.placeAt(stuff);
        table.setModel(model);
        table.bindRows({
            'path': '/root',
            'parameters': {
                'arrayNames': ['children']
            },
            'factory': function (id, context) {
                console.log(id);
                return new sap.ui.table.Row({
                    'cells': [
                        new sap.ui.commons.TextView({'text': '{label}'})
                    ]
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please submit the code here on SO. jsbin will not be available too long in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging and checking the source code, I found that 'TreeTable' doesn't handle the factory function. As the aggregation 'rows' is a TreeBinding and it will override the 'attachChange(fModelChangeHandler)'. So that it's behaviour is different from the 'ListBinding' such as 'items' which the factory function will be called if it is passed in.